# Does this iOS UITableView need restructuring in order to allow accessibility and automation?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios-ui-automation, uiaccessibility

I've got an app which was developed by an outside company, and am attempting to use UI-Automation (or Appium) to get some basic regression tests up. However, certain buttons on the page are inaccessible, despite having accessibility and labels.

I compiled in Reveal and looked at the view structure:

```
UITableView
  UITableViewWrapperView
  SlideShowView (subclass of UIView)
    UIButton: Sign In
    UIButton: Sign Up
  _UITableViewCellSeparatorView
  _UITableViewCellSeparatorView (repeated 16 more times)
```

SlideShowView is not inside a cell. This seems very strange.

UI-Automation and Appium show a UITableView with an auto-generated label of "Empty list". The Sign In and Sign Up buttons are not accessible.

Is there any precedent for this, or is it just a broken layout that is rendered correctly by pure luck? It seems to be the equivalent of:

```
<table>
  <div></div>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right. That's a surprising view hierarchy that isn't trivially accessible. Unfortunately, this means there is no citable reference.